# Issue with code P: PP Drill 4

Tags: c++, vector

I've been doing a drill from a book entitled Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup, and this drill (Chapter `4`) primarily deals with vectors. When I run the program, it doesn't give me any output at all. There are no compilation errors though. Here's the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    vector<double> value;
    vector<string> units;
    double max_val=-100000, min_val=100000;
    double temp, sum=0;
    int no_of_inputs=0;
    string unit;
    int i=0;

    cout << "\nEnter the first value: " << endl;

    // inputs values and units and assign them in vector value and vector unit respectively.
    while (cin >> temp >> unit){
        ++no_of_inputs;
        cout << "Enter the next value: " << endl;
        value.push_back(temp);
        units.push_back(unit);
    }

    // converts cm, in and ft to m; 
    for (i==0; i<units.size(); ++i){        
        if (units[i]== "cm" || units[i]== " cm"){
                value[i] = value[i]/100.0;
        }else if (units[i]== "in" || units[i]== " in"){
                value[i] = value[i]/2.5/100.0;
        }else if (units[i]== "ft" || units[i]== " ft"){
                value[i] = value[i]*12/2.5/100.0;
        }else if (units[i]=="m" || units[i]== " m"){
            }else cout << "\n\n" << value[i] << " " << units[i] << " is an incorrect input value."; 
        return 0;
    }

    // Identifies the max_value and the min_value. Also adds all values.
    for (i==0; i<value.size(); ++i){
        if (value[i]>max_val){
            max_val=value[i];
        }
        if (value[i]<min_val){
        min_val=value[i];
        }           
        sum += value[i];
    }

    // outputs all values entered (converted to meters)
    cout << "\nValues Entered:"<< endl;
    sort(value);
    for (i==0; i<value.size(); ++i){
        cout << value[i] << " meters" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Total: " << sum << " meters" << endl;
    cout << "Smallest value: " << min_val << endl;
    cout << "Largest value: " << max_val << endl;
    cout << "Total values entered: " << no_of_inputs << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: *Can anyone tell me why it's not working?* -- Before anyone tells you why it isn't working, note that debugging your own programs is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  Don't make it a habit of writing a program, seeing it doesn't work, and then automatically go to stackoverflow to have someone else debug your program.  Also -- *There are no compilation errors though* -- All that means is that there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.

Comment: `for (i==0;` should be `for (i=0;`. Otherwise the code just tests the value of `i`, instead of giving it a new value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay. Yeah, should have looked closely first. Thanks.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 mistakes. The main reason for terminating your program is here

```
else cout << "\n\n" << value[i] << " " << units[i] << " is an incorrect input value."; return 0;
```

you putting **return** in the first for loop. I guess you may think return is belong to else but because you don't use scope determiner **{}** only 1 instruction **(cout)** is belong to else and return is executed every time.

your second mistake is use i==0 instead of i=0 in for loops.

your correct code is this :

```
vector<double> value;
vector<string> units;
double max_val = -100000, min_val = 100000;
double temp, sum = 0;
int no_of_inputs = 0;
string unit;
int i = 0;

cout << "\nEnter the first value: " << endl;

//inputs values and units and assign them in vector value and vector unit respectively.
while (cin >> temp >> unit){
    ++no_of_inputs;
    cout << "Enter the next value: " << endl;
    value.push_back(temp);
    units.push_back(unit);
}

//converts cm, in and ft to m;

for (i = 0; i<units.size(); ++i){

    if (units[i] == "cm" || units[i] == " cm"){
        value[i] = value[i] / 100.0;
    }
    else if (units[i] == "in" || units[i] == " in"){
        value[i] = value[i] / 2.5 / 100.0;
    }
    else if (units[i] == "ft" || units[i] == " ft"){
        value[i] = value[i] * 12 / 2.5 / 100.0;
    }
    else if (units[i] == "m" || units[i] == " m")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\n" << value[i] << " " << units[i] << " is an incorrect input value."; 
    return 0;
    }

}

//Identifies the max_value and the min_value. Also adds all values.
for (i = 0; i<value.size(); ++i){

    if (value[i]>max_val){
        max_val = value[i];
    }
    if (value[i]<min_val){
        min_val = value[i];
    }

    sum += value[i];
}

//outputs all values entered (converted to meters)
cout << "\nValues Entered:" << endl;
//sort(value);
for (i = 0; i<value.size(); ++i){
    cout << value[i] << " meters" << endl;
}

cout << "Total: " << sum << " meters" << endl;
cout << "Smallest value: " << min_val << endl;
cout << "Largest value: " << max_val << endl;
cout << "Total values entered: " << no_of_inputs << endl;

return 0;
```